# How to avoid the scientific notation in output?

Tags: output-formatting

I was trying with `DecimalForm`, but I read that the suitable one is `NumberForm[0.5^20, 12]` from version 11.

But when I evaluate

```
NumberForm[0.5^20, 12]
```

Mathematica 11 shows the result in scientific notation. How can I obtain the output in pure decimal notation?

Comment: You can use an option like `NumberForm[0.5^20, {12, 11}, 
 ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-100, 100}]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Math 11 says NumberForm::optx: Unknown option ScientificNotationThreshold in NumberForm[9.53674 10^(-7),{12,11},ScientificNotationThreshold->{-100,100}]. 
Mathematica it´s so complicate for simple things!! and so beautifull in other ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `AccountingForm` consult help for it.
I tried and look the result

```
AccountingForm[0.2^20, 40]

0.0000000000000104857600000000
```

Comment: @MikaIke You might not be happy with AccountingForm when using negative numbers!

Answer (score 13):

Before M11.2 you can use [`ExponentFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExponentFunction):

```
NumberForm[0.5^20, 12, ExponentFunction->(Null&)]
```

> 0.000000953674316406

In M11.2 you can also use the option [`ScientificNotationThreshold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScientificNotationThreshold) as suggested by @b.gatessucks:

```
NumberForm[0.5^20, 12, ScientificNotationThreshold->{-Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 0.000000953674316406

Instead of [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm), you could use [`DecimalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DecimalForm):

```
DecimalForm[.5^20]
```

> 0.000000953674316406