# Why don't AccountingForm, NumberForm and DecimalForm print more decimals?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, input-forms, output-formatting

I have the following set of equations:

```
xs = 9295050963679385441209;
ys = 10721945986215692199666;
x = xs - 10000;
exponent = 0.666451549104308964``18;
xs1gt = Power[xs,exponent];
```

Which should produce ~437295921404696.997750975489799605.

If I naively print `xs1gt`, I get this:

```
4.372959214046970*10^14
```

I looked for solutions on StackExchange, and I found the [How to avoid the scientific notation in output?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161145/how-to-avoid-the-scientific-notation-in-output) thread. Unfortunately, none of the solutions proposed there worked:

```
AccountingForm[xs1gt, 33]
DecimalForm[xs1gt, {15, 18}]
N[xs1gt, 33]
NumberForm[xs1gt, 33]
NumberForm[xs1gt, 33, ExponentFunction->(Null&)]
NumberForm[xs1gt, 33, ScientificNotationThreshold->{-Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Outputs:

```
437295921404697.0
437295921404697.000000000000000000
4.372959214046970*10^14
4.372959214046970*10^14
437295921404697.0
437295921404697.0
```

I searched high and low for alternatives, and I stumbled upon [InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) and [SetPrecision](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html), which finally gave me satisfactory results:

```
InputForm[xs1gt]
SetPrecision[xs1gt, 33]
```

Outputs:

```
4.372959214046969977509754897996045`16.295988813986288*10^14
4.37295921404696997750975489799605*^14
```

Now my question is why didn't the other approaches, i.e. `AccountingForm`, `DecimalForm` and `NumberForm`, produce a similar result with 33 significant figures of precision (15 digits and 18 decimals)? I am especially confused by `DecimalForm` not having worked the way I expected.

Comment: The requested precision in the `*Form` wrapper seems not override the precision of the number and uses the precision as a limit on the number of sig figs, with excess digits being padded with zero if necessary. It is similar to the behavior of `RealDigits` and fits with the Mathematica notion of `Precision`. Is `DecimalForm[SetPrecision[xs1gt, 33], {33, 18}]` a good enough workaround?

Comment: Yes, using "DecimalForm" together with "SetPrecision" is a good solution for me. I wanted to understand why the other solutions didn't work though, an issue which is addressed by the first part of your comment.

Comment: A simplistic explanation is that 18 is not enough accuracy for `exponent`.  Try these two modifications:  `exponent = SetAccuracy[0.666451549104308964, 50]`  (or use the double backtick form) and `DecimalForm[xs1gt, {33, 18}]`.  Does this give the desired result?

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks @LouisB!!